# hadoop parallel processing examples or documentation

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming, hadoop-plugins

I'm new to Hadoop and I'm not able to find basic examples for this so that i can get the required start. I don't know if this a right place to ask or not but I feel the professionals related to this can help me.

Please help me on this by examples or documentation.

Thanks in advance

Pawan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "not able to find basic examples"? there are thousands of examples if you google them.[Here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html) is "hello world" sort of  word count example straight from apache hadoop documentation.

Comment: Please read hadoop parallel processing examples